# Simple flutter app that doesn't use Firebase gives Firebase error on launch

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I created a simple Flutter app using the default template and made a few changes to it. It was working fine until I tried to add some plugins, then it started complaining about [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14020). I tried various proposed fixes but then I started getting this error:

> AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.myapp. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

I eventually gave up and went back to the previous working state (as far as I know) and ran `flutter clean`. However `flutter clean` does not appear to actually clean everything because I still get the error.

I have never added anything to do with Firebase! And I didn't get that error when I first created the app. What is going on?

Comment: Did you removed all unwanted libraries from your  `pubspec.yaml `. Could you please post it? Moreover, is this project under versioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was depending on `android_alarm_manager`. I thought that was fine, because I added it and did hot-reload and everything worked ok (at least the app didn't crash immediately). However you only get the Firebase error when you do a proper rebuild (`flutter run`).

But why does an *alarm manager* depend on Firebase? I don't know but.. [it does](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/android_alarm_manager/pubspec.yaml#L9). I know WTF right?

[Its readme](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/android_alarm_manager/README.md) also doesn't mention anything about this, or the fact that you have to call `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)` or whatever.

Comment: Coincidentally someone opened an issue about this this very hour: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25417

Comment: From looking at the code, it looks like the Flutter sample for the alarm manager uses Firebase Authentication. So the dependency should just be specified for the sample app, not for the library. Reporting this on the repo is the correct approach here.

Comment: I ran into this issue with the [qr_mobile_vision](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_mobile_vision) package. I decided to upgrade to the latest version without reading the details there.  Thanks to your post (not sure why the down vote?) and answer, I read their notes more carefully, and found this: *"If you are only targeting android and don't want to switch to Firebase Mobile Vision from Google Mobile Vision, use a 0.\* version of the plugin."*